# Having trouble with "cannot find symbol" - Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am receiving the following three `cannot find symbol` errors, and I am not sure why!

```
GrammerQueue.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor GrammerStructure()
location: class GrammerStructure
public class GrammerQueue extends GrammerStructure implements StringQueue{
           ^
GrammerQueue.java:45: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable stack
location: class GrammerQueue
           this.stack += tmpAr[i];
                ^
GrammerQueue.java:47: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable count
location: class GrammerQueue
       this.count--;
            ^
3 errors
```

I got this error on another script and solved it by calling a new object of that type instead of directly calling the object my class creates. However, I'm not even trying to create an object yet! What can I do?

Here's the code:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class GrammerQueue extends GrammerStructure implements StringQueue {

    private String queue = "";
    private String structName;

    // @override
    public boolean offer(String item) {
        if (item.length() == 0) // We don't accept empty Strings!
            return false;
        else if (this.queue.length() == 0) // If new queue, just add - no null.
            queue = item;
        else
            // Append null and item for seperation.
            queue += "\0" + item;
        return true; // done.
    }

    // @override
    public String[] asArray() {
        // Splits the string at each null character and returns it as an array.
        String[] array = this.queue.split("\0");
        return array;
    }

    // @override
    public void GrammerStructure(String structureName) {
        this.structName = structureName;
    }

    // @override
    public String take() throws EmptyException {
        // If empty, throw errors.
        if (this.queue.length() == 0)
            throw new EmptyException(structName);
        String[] tmpAr = this.asArray();
        // Empties the stac now that we have it in a temp array.
        this.queue = "";
        // FIFO, so exclude first element in reconstruction.
        for (int i = 1; i < tmpAr.length; i++)
            this.stack += tmpAr[i];
        // We made it this far without error, so reduce count.
        this.count--;
        // Return the first item.
        return tmpAr[0];
    }

    // @override
    public String peek() {
        // Empty string check.
        if (this.queue.length() == 0)
            return null;
        String[] tmpAr = this.asArray();
        // Return the first item.
        return tmpAr[0];
    }

    // @override
    public int size() {
        if (this.queue.length() == 0)
            return 0;
        String[] tmpAr = this.asArray();
        return tmpAr.length;
    }

    // @override
    public void clear() throws EmptyException {
        // If empty, throw errors.
        if (this.queue.length() == 0)
            throw new EmptyException(structName);
        else
            this.queue = ""; // Empty now.
    }

    public void main(String args[]) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `stack` and `count` variable. You need to declare and define them, and create getters and setters probably.

You need to import a package for GrammerStructure, assuming GrammerStructure is in a different package.

Comment: Thank you, I had copied a segment of this code from another of mine like it and missed that, I had completely forgotten my constructor!

Comment: @user1695505.. If that solved your problem.. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.. Click the arrow besides the answer..

Comment: Sorry, had to leave and it wouldn't let me approve so quickly. It works fine now, thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

GrammerQueue extends GrammerStructure, which is a class that doesn't exist (AFAIK).